# Using rxjs SwitchMap with Async FormControl Validator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to combine SwitchMap with Async Validator, I have created the following Async validator but the SwitchMap cancel behavior for previous requests is not working!

What I'm missing here ?

```
static emailValidator(userService: UsersService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return of(control.value).pipe(
        switchMap(
          value => userService.validateEmail(value)
        ),
        map(
          (res: {isValid: boolean}) => {
            return res.isValid ? null : {username: false};
          }
        ),
        catchError(
          (err) => {
            return of({username: false});
          }
        )
      );
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you're creating a new observable everytime, so the source is never emitting again so it never switches. This is all redundant anyway as async validators handle canceling automatically, just do this:

```
static emailValidator(userService: UsersService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return userService.validateEmail(control.value).pipe(
        map(
          (res: {isValid: boolean}) => {
            return res.isValid ? null : {username: false};
          }
        ),
        catchError(
          (err) => {
            return of({username: false});
          }
        )
      );
    };
  }
```

blitz demonstrating this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqjgbe?file=src/app/app.component.ts

if you want to avoid sending the request at all on new values (debounce it)... this is easy;

```
static emailValidator(userService: UsersService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return timer(300).pipe( // timer will debounce for you
        switchMapTo(userService.validateEmail(control.value)),
        map(
          (res: {isValid: boolean}) => {
            return res.isValid ? null : {username: false};
          }
        ),
        catchError(
          (err) => {
            return of({username: false});
          }
        )
      );
    };
  }
```

Comment: This was my initial solution but it is not working either!

Comment: I mean this is how async validators work. When a new value comes in, previous subscriptions are canceled.

Comment: I added a blitz demonstrating this. If your goal is to actually avoid sending the request at all if a new value comes in, this is very easy to achieve

Comment: My goal is to unsubscribe form previous observable when new value comes.

Comment: as the blitz i added demonstrates, this happens automatically.

Comment: check this gif, when user enter new value into email field the async validator should unsubscribe from the previous: https://gph.is/g/aejxVAr

Comment: unless you're on angular 3 or something, you're doing something else wrong. I updated the blitz to use actual http responses to demonstrate that this works as expected. Either produce a stackblitz that replicates the issue or figure out where you're actually going wrong.

Comment: you are right, this happens automatically but I didn't figure it up why this not happening in my case !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an observable with `of(control.value)` you need to use `control.valueChanges`:

```js
static emailValidator(userService: UsersService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return control.valueChanges.pipe(
        switchMap(
          value => userService.validateEmail(value)
        ),
        map(
          (res: {isValid: boolean}) => {
            return res.isValid ? null : {username: false};
          }
        ),
        catchError(
          (err) => {
            return of({username: false});
          }
        )
      );
    };
  }
```

Comment: This will not work for sure, and you will end up subscribing multiple times .

Comment: What do you mean by "subscribing multiple times". switchMap will unsubscribe from previous observable returned from `userService.validateEmail` and subscribe to the new one. So only one subscription at a time.

Comment: That is the problem, SwitchMap not unsubscribing from previous observable. In your approach you are subscribing after the control value changes so only in the next emit it will run the validateEmail function.
check this GIF: https://gph.is/g/aRm7eG6